# Using Node.JS and Unirest for REST client over HTTPS throwing certificate issue

Tags: node.js, rest, ssl, unirest

I  am attempting to create my first REST client in Node.JS using Unirest.  It is intended to communicate with a Flask RestPlus server that is proxied through Nginx over port 443.  I can access the Swagger docs in Chrome with no SSL issues.  The SSL cert is not self-signed, and is issued through Digicert and is internal to where I work.  When I attempt 'get' requests using Unirest I am getting a `unable to get local issuer certificate`.  I can add the 'strictSSL(false)' function to my api call and the error goes away, but I would prefer not to turn off SSL checking.  I have looked all over Google for an answer, but have not been able to dig anything up.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am running Node.JS in a Windows 10 envir0nment for dev/testing, but once finished the code will be deployed into a Cloud Foundry/Linux environment.

Node.JS code:
`unirest.get("https://path/to/api/call").headers(headers).end(function (res) { console.log(res); });`

Error that is given:

> { error:
>     { Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
>         at Error (native)
>         at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1062:38)
>         at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>         at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
>         at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
>         at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38) code: >'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY' } }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution this!  Using the `ssl-root-cas` module and adding the following code to the top of my rest-client file the issue was resolved.

```
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
rootCas.addFile(__dirname + '/path/to/ca.pem');
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;
```

Hopefully someone else will find this useful if experiencing the same issue.