# self signed certificate in certificate chain error for nodejs API Basic authentication

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, python-requests, basic-authentication, unirest

I am trying to add data to my elastic search index using REST API and it works fine in POSTMAN. I also tried the same with a python script with request which is working.

But the same fails with nodejs. It is giving me self **signed certificate in certificate chain** error.

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
console.log("start");
var req = unirest('PUT', 'https://24.73.543.228:9001/accelerators/_doc/12')
  .headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpQYXNzd29yZEAxcjdcMjM0='
  })
  .send(JSON.stringify({"name":"ajj","type":"test","description":"khukhkd","created_date":"2021-02-18T20:20:41.560Z"}))
  .end(function (res) { 
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error); 
    console.log(res.raw_body);
  });
```

This is the error.

```
Error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at C:\Users\Desktop\test.js:10:26
    at Request.handleRequestResponse [as _callback] (C:\Users\node_modules\unirest\index.js:444:15)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\Bittu.Raju\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\Bittu.Raju\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
```

Tried the basic authentication

```
auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
```

And tried using the auth variable in header still with same error.

Tried the same with Python requests and it works fine. How to make it work in nodejs.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
url="https://24.73.543.228:9001/accelerators/_doc/12"
print(url)
payload=dataJson[i]
print(payload)
payload=json.dumps(payload)
print(type(payload))
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('usern', 'Password@123'),verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your certificate is self-signed, you can simply try to not verify it by calling `strictSSL(false)`:

```
var req = unirest('PUT', 'https://24.73.543.228:9001/accelerators/_doc/12')
  .strictSSL(false)       <---- add this line
  .headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpQYXNzd29yZEAxcjdcMjM0='
  })
  .send(JSON.stringify({"name":"ajj","type":"test","description":"khukhkd","created_date":"2021-02-18T20:20:41.560Z"}))
  .end(function (res) { 
     ...
```

Another option is to specify the self-signed CA certificate using [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121665/4604579)